React-native RichTextBox wants To recieve same data on next Screen
ReacT-native RichTextBox Navigation data and passing data between Screens
i want to have a rich text box on one screen where whatever i write will be displayed on the next screen, just like whatever was written in the text box on the previous screen will be shown there.
